# Cache size and sort size in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, caching

Reading [the article](http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/hw_performance/) about PosgtreSQL effective settings, I came across the `cache size` and `sort size` concepts. As there said, these two sizes don't depend on each other.

> Both cache size and sort size affect memory usage, so you cannot
>   maximize one without affecting the other

[Googling](https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=sort%20size%20postgresql) didn't get too much useful results. As far as I got, the cache size can be viewed with

```
SELECT current_setting('shared_buffers') AS shared_buffers
```

This returns the size of shared buffers (i.e. cache). But what is the sort size?

Comment: Check this [Link](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/hw_performance/) ;).

Answer (score 1):

Sort_mem parameter, mentioned in Bruce's artice, is the same as *work_mem* (e.g. http://postgresql.nabble.com/sort-mem-param-of-postgresql-conf-td1910195.html).

This parameter specifies the amount of memory to be used for sort and hash operations. It is part of local backend memory, while shared buffers reside in global memory of the server.

See the doc: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html